# Why str.cat is much faster than lambda expression in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I just started coding in python. As a beginner, I tested different ways of coding to see their efficiency. I had a dataframe `review` storing a number of columns and I want to concatenate each row of two columns - `country` and `variety` - with a delimiter '-'.

If I try lambda expression for doing the job, it will be like this:

```
start = time.time()
ans = reviews[['country','variety']]
ans = ans.dropna(axis = "index", how = "any")
ans = ans.apply(lambda srs: srs.country + " - " + srs.variety, axis = "columns")
ans.value_counts()
end = time.time()
print(end - start)
# time elapsed: 3.825517416000366
```

If I try str.cat method, it will be like this:

```
start = time.time()
ans = reviews[['country','variety']]
ans = ans.dropna(axis = "index", how = "any")
ans = ans.country.str.cat(ans.variety, sep = ' - ')
ans.value_counts()
end = time.time()
print(end - start)
# time elapsed: 0.14058899879455566
```

I wonder why there is such a big discrepancy in efficiency?

Comment: Let's straighten something out here. It isn't _just_ the lambda. Yes, that has a role to play, but you may want to look at the function itself -- apply is notoriously slower than even the slowest of vanilla loops that do the same thing. There's just too much overhead for it to be of any good performance wise. Avoid like the plague.

Answer (score 0):

**You should avoid to use lambda expressions with pandas.**

`.str.cat()` is a Series'method and is designed to transform easily the whole pandas serie whereas lamba creates a fonction that is not part of pandas and it browses every line one by one.